# Multiple matching substring selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a rule to match all classes beginning with `icon-` which also have the `btn` class. `[class^="icon-"] {` matches the first condition, but how do I add "that also have the .btn class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works:

```
.btn[class*="icon-"]
```

So will,

```
[class*="icon-"][class~="btn"]
```

Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VaACP/1/

Comment: Don't confuse this with CSS2 `[class~=icon]` which searches for the whole word - ideal for fullname class matching, but not for the substring of a substring class matching

Answer (score 9):

#### Finding `icon-` at the Start

You could try the following - the icon class would need to be first in the attribute:

```
[class^='icon-'].btn
```

To this HTML

```
<div class="icon-1 btn">Foo</div>  <!-- Matched -->
<div class="icon-2 btn">Bar</div>  <!-- Matched -->
<div class="btn icon-3">Fizz</div> <!-- Not Matched -->
<div class="icon btn">Buzz</div>   <!-- Not Matched -->
```

#### Finding `icon-` Within (Caution!)

You could modify the query to base the class search on a substring:

```
[class*='icon-'].btn
```

But note that this will turn up positive with classes that *resemble* `icon-`, like `myicon-1` or `noicon-2`.

#### Finding `icon-` Anywhere Within

If you're unsure of where the `icon-` class will show up in the attribute, you could look for both examples:

```
[class^='icon-'].btn, [class*=' icon-'].btn
```

This will find `icon-` classes at the beginning, or anywhere within (preceded by a space).

```
<div class="icon-1 btn">Foo</div>  <!-- Matched -->
<div class="icon-2 btn">Bar</div>  <!-- Matched -->
<div class="btn icon-3">Fizz</div> <!-- Matched -->
<div class="icon btn">Buzz</div>   <!-- Not Matched -->
```